# What is the name of this kind of through-hole fastener?

Tags: terminology, home-improvement

I've seen these before but I don't know what they're called. It's a two piece insert that creates a through-hole between them.

I drew a picture to help identity it!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If it is a threaded two-piece item, you'll find it by searching "binder bolt" among other terms:

[image: binder bolt]

Image above courtesy of [The Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-16-in-x-1-2-in-Aluminum-Slotted-Drive-Truss-Head-Binding-Posts-and-Screws-50-Pack-9051715/310667175?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&mtc=Shopping-VF-F_D25H-G-D25H-Multi-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-GiftCenter&cm_mmc=Shopping-VF-F_D25H-G-D25H-Multi-Multi-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-GiftCenter-71700000075074702-58700006462421696-92700058414792291&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-rj9BRCAARIsANB_4ABNmEKz-45xA5MRa88m8v0Jw5YVFxbpySZZszdZgOIjcgMIuj61-C8aAm-CEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds), multiple sources abound, various length are manufactured, various diameters too.

Comment: Apparently the correct term is "[sex bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_bolt)". Using any of the many other terms might avoid strange looks in the hardware store.

Comment: Decades ago, these bolts held together ledgers in which bookkeepers managed accounting and finance by hand. As the number of pages increased, binder bolts of a greater capacity were required. The term "sex bolt" is not the "correct" term, just one of many other terms.

Comment: This doesn't look correct as OPs illustration has a through-hole after assembly

Comment: @JonathanRSwift through hole? or just the hex for tuning the top part? no hidden detail on the drawing to confirm a through hole...

Comment: It's stated as being a through hole in the title *and* the question detail! Circle rather than hex in illustration is not conclusive I agree, but taken together...

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that my answer does not properly solve the original question for lack of through-hole, but will not delete it unless strongly suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

[image]

It's called a "Steel Threaded Double Flared Eyelet"
Looks like its something jewelry supply stores sell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are thinking of is probably a copper hollow rivet.

Answer (score 0):

Type "threaded insert" into Google image search and scroll until you see something similar to what you are looking for, then see what it's called

Comment: Threaded Inserts don't have a flat end like a bolt.